# Called within transaction When UIsearch Bar clicked and keyboard showed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, catransaction

I did a ViewController where there is a button and UITextfield when I click the button a UITableViewController with a UISearchBar is presented and a list of languages is displayed. My issue is when I run the app the first time I click the button and then click the UISearchBar on my console I have this warning

> SearchDebugApp[2237:558457] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
>   SearchDebugApp[2237:558457] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
>   SearchDebugApp[2237:558457] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction
>   SearchDebugApp[2237:558457] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

this message happens only the first time I click on the UISearchBar nothing seems to go wrong with the app so I don't now why this is happening and how should I debug it .

I searched on this message warning I found out that This happens when more than one animation are taking place on main thread  but in my app the only animation that is happening is when the keyboard is showed .

[You can clone project here](https://github.com/czakaria/SearchDebugApp)

Comment: This looks like a bug within the UISearchController or UINavigationController (or a combination of both).  I created a test project with nothing but a UIViewController inside a UINavigationController and added the UISearchController and it still gives those same four warnings when you first tap on the search bar.  It doesn't appear to cause problems and I can't see any way to get rid of it.

Comment: First thanks for the time that you put to help others it`s really apreciated :)  Second so you thing i should just ignore this  error ? and Do you think my app could be rejected for those messages ? thanks !

Comment: I would be very surprised as they are just internal warnings and we have had a few messages like that and our app has never been rejected for it. (Sorry for the delay I had a 2 hour drive home)

Comment: no problem ! ok then it`s good to know  thanks again

Comment: @cczak I tried it today with iOS 11.3 SDK. Same here. ( Navigation controller with tableViewController and searchController searchBar together )

Comment: I have the same warning. Have any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is happening even on Apple example project:
[Table Search with UISearchController example](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)

You can download the project and run it, you will see the same 4
[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction