# +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction when search

Tags: ios, swift4, uisearchcontroller, catransaction

I implemented a searchController and added in navigationItem.

That's code:

```
var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "")
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true

// Layout
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

When I click in searchBar to write something, this warning appears in console:

> NameOfProject[9238:211033] +[CATransaction synchronize] called within
>   transaction NameOfProject[9238:211033] +[CATransaction synchronize]
>   called within transaction NameOfProject[9238:211033] +[CATransaction
>   synchronize] called within transaction NameOfProject[9238:211033]
>   +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

Please, someone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

There exists a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144576/called-within-transaction-when-uisearch-bar-clicked-and-keyboard-showed).

This post states that this behavior might be a bug on iOS side, because it also occurs in a minimal example containing just a single UIViewController which contains a UISearchController and is embedded in a UINavigationController (see comment of [Upholder Of Truth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8111753/upholder-of-truth)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't find a way to remove this warning, too. It really seem to be a bug on iOS side...